# Resize dynamically a JTable through a JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, resize, jtable

I am thinking about how can I implement a resizeable `JTable` (I want it squared), through a `JSpinner`.

So I search and found techniques to add columns like :

```
    TableColumn toAdd = new TableColumn();
    toAdd.setHeaderValue("col1");
    toAdd.setIdentifier("col1");
    toAdd.setPreferredWidth("col1".length());
    this.addColumn(toAdd);
    this.moveColumn(this.getColumnCount() - 1, 3);
    this.validate();
```

And similar to remove ones :

```
TableColumn j = this.getColumn(0);
this.removeColumn(j);
this.validate()
```

But it gives me troubles with renderers as the last column and the first one are indexes with a specific visuals attributes.

I'm now considering destroying the `JTable` (or at least the model) and create a new one each time one resize, but it seems I missed something. Someone have another idea ?

Comment: If you don't need the data then just recreate the TableModel and add the custom renderers back to the table.

Comment: A couple of questions:

1) Does your table already have columns?

2) What is bounding the max size of your table? (Parent window, some parent panel, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't *recreate* the `JTable` *or* the `TableModel`. Instead, extend [`AbstractTableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) and update the model's internal data structure. Invoking `fireTableStructureChanged()` will let the listening table know to render itself. Invoke `resize()` in your spinner's `ChangeListener`.

```
public void resize(int rows, int cols) {
    init(rows, cols);
    this.fireTableStructureChanged();
}
```

The model need not be square; an `n` by `n+1` model, for example, will let you treat the last column specially, for example in a [system of linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations). If your model contains instances of `Double`, for example, add your [renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) by `class` rather than by column and alter the color for the last column.

Comment: I have already try that too. Do you mean that I just should modify my model and call `fireTableStructureChanged()` ?

Comment: Yes, but you must do so from _within_ the `TableModel`.